# Вопрос по объекту webbrowser в visual studio

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток!

У меня возникла проблема. Когда я монтировал свой новый веб-браузер, я обратил внимание на то, что при щелкании по ссылке "Новое окно" открывается iexplore.exe со ссылкой, а хотелось бы, чтобы ссылка прогружалась в том же элементе. Я понимаю, что надо обрабатывать событие webbrowser1.newwindow, но не понимаю, как ТОЧНО это сделать. Пробовал удалять процесс iexplore - не пашет.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Извините, товарищ Гном!
Я нашел более простое решение, только чуть-чуть левое :Р

```
webbrowser1.navigate(webbrowser1.statustext,false)
e.cancel=true
```

Все равно спасибо)))

Answer (score 0):

В С++ это делается за счет настройки самого IE, через реестр. Самый ломовой способ - вам необходимо найти параметр в IE, на вроде "Всегда открывать в текущем окне", и посмотреть, что записывается в реестр при этих действиях. Далее, из кода меняем значение реестра.